# Which additives increase shellac's heat resistance?

Tags: finishing

I like shellac's color and ease of application, but the bottom of my laptop melts my table's finish. Yes, seriously.

I'm thinking to cross-link the finish (taking advantage of all the hydroxyl and carboxyl groups) by mixing it with a bit of epoxy or epoxy hardener (polyamine). (Note: shellac is pretty reactive, which is probably one reason it works as a primer. It will crosslink all by itself, if the heat is high enough.)

Do you know of anything else that can be added to shellac to make it cross-link or increase the heat tolerance? I don't like the idea of adding epoxy or hardener because it may have a very short pot life. I might also be able to try mixing it with lacquer. What additives would you try?

Comment: Nothing I'm aware of. If you need heat resistance you should just go with varnish like almost everyone does, poly being the best option for you most likely. Varnish can be exactly the same colour as many versions of shellac and it can be just as easy to apply to a high standard (arguably slightly easier).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Supposedly this company figured out a suitable additive: http://www.ubeaut.com.au/hardshell.htm

But the chemical mix I have in mind (basically epoxy) would not be shelf-stable for even two days, and their product supposedly is.

Comment: You might try asking at [chemistry.se], since it seems like a chemical question and that you've got the background to understand the answers. :)